# coincidently VERSUS coincidentally

Tags: meaning

I hear controversial opinions on the difference between **coincidently** and **coincidentally**

Some say they mean the same, others say they are different.

"Coincidently" means it's happening at the same time.

"I made breakfast, coincidently [at the same time], my husband did the dishes."

"Coincidentally" is when the chances of two things happening at the same are very low, but they happen anyway. (Though this word gets used in place of "coincidently" quite frequently).

What say you?

Comment: I had always assumed that _coincidently_ was a misspelling of _coincidentally_, but some dictionaries (_not_ Oxford Languages) seem to treat it as a separate word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you're right, but the trouble is most people don't recognise the difference. They think one is a misspelling.

Even dictionaries will use 'coincidentally' to mean 'at the same time', where in casual usage, a coincidence is something that appears related, or even some kind of cause and effect, but isn't necessarily. They don't have to actually occur at the same time; the meaning has drifted slightly away from that to almost now mean by accident as opposed to intentionally.

"I went on holiday to Benidorm this year"
"Oh, what a coincidence. I went there last year."

True temporal coincidence has been removed, leaving only 'two similar events'.

Coincidently, however, retains its sense of temporal simultaneity, or at least congruence or an agreement.

I think the best differentiation I can manage is that one has become a subset of the other.
Coincidentally can encompass temporal simultaneity as well as accidental similarity but coincidently only includes simultaneity.

---

True story, happened today at my local supermarket.
My partner was speaking with one of the shop assistants, who mentioned having recently moved there from a town quite some distance away, to our corner of a very large city.

"Oh, I think my friend mentioned you recently in conversation. She spoke of someone who had just moved to our locality from there & was working for this supermarket chain."

Which would you define as the coincidence? The meeting? The prior conversation with a friend? That we actually met the person her friend had previously mentioned? The whole lot, all happening at once… even though they were all separated in time and place until the actual discovery that brought them all together?
[I don't have an answer to that, btw, it's rhetorical.]
It would definitely have to be 'coincidentally' though, as there was no aspect of it that was temporally coincident, other than the final conjunction of all the components.

Answer (score 0):

coincidence, the noun:

Adjectives: coincident
AND
coincidental

The difference is this:

> As adjectives the difference between coincident and coincidental is
> that **coincident is occurring at the same time** while **coincidental is
> occurring as or resulting from coincidence**.

[difference between the two forms](https://wikidiff.com/coincident/coincidental)

**The corresponding adverbs would then be: coincidently and coincidentally**

Answer (score 0):

The Oxford English Dictionary has entries for both spellings. But the meaning given is the same - ***coincidently*** - "In a coincident manner; concurrently, at the same time."

The entry for ***coincidentally*** simply refers back, as an alternative spelling to *coincidently*.

Neither are ascribed any meaning such as "in the manner of a coincidence".

The problem here is that the original meaning of the noun ***coincidence*** simply had to do with "the fact of being coincident" in time or space.

The sense which emerged largely in the 19th century of a ***coincidence*** being "A notable concurrence of events or circumstances having no apparent causal connection", which is nowadays its foremost one, is only listed as OED sense 4.

But the OED does not lay down any clear marker that ***coincidentally*** is the adverb which applies to the modern (sense 4) of ***coincidence***.